# What Permission should I grant to allow some Contacts to sens SMS's

Tags: sms

I have just installed Twilio Extension (to send SMS's)

What permission must I grant to enable some Contacts to send SMS's (currently, SMS - schedule/send action is only available to me (administrator))

Answer (score 2):

Edit All Contacts.

But this is not appropriate (too permissive) : I would prefer a specific, or merged with CiviMail permission.